# Grails: Querying Associations causes groovy.lang.MissingMethodException

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I've got an issue with Grails where I have a test app with:

```
class Artist {
static constraints = {
 name()
}

 static hasMany = [albums:Album]
 String name
}

class Album {
 static constraints = {
  name()
}

 static hasMany = [ tracks : Track ]
 static belongsTo = [artist: Artist]

 String name
}

class Track {

 static constraints = {
  name()
  lyrics(nullable: true)
 }

 Lyrics lyrics
 static belongsTo = [album: Album]

 String name
}
```

The following query (and a more advanced, nested association query) works in the Grails Console but fails with a groovy.lang.MissingMethodException when running the app with 'run-app':

```
def albumCriteria = tunehub.Album.createCriteria()
def albumResults = albumCriteria.list {
 like("name", receivedAlbum)
 artist { like("name", receivedArtist) } // Fails here
maxResults(1)
}
```

Stacktrace:

```
groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.lang.String.call() is applicable for argument types: (tunehub.LyricsService$_getLyrics_closure1_closure2) values: [tunehub.LyricsService$_getLyrics_closure1_closure2@604106]
Possible solutions: wait(), any(), wait(long), each(groovy.lang.Closure), any(groovy.lang.Closure), trim()
at tunehub.LyricsService$_getLyrics_closure1.doCall(LyricsService.groovy:61)
at tunehub.LyricsService$_getLyrics_closure1.doCall(LyricsService.groovy)
(...truncated...)
```

Any pointers?

Comment: Can you provide the `MissingMethodException` stack trace?

Comment: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.lang.String.call() is applicable for argument types: (tunehub.LyricsService$_getLyrics_closure1_closure2) values: [tunehub.LyricsService$_getLyrics_closure1_closure2@604106]Possible solutions: wait(), any(), wait(long), each(groovy.lang.Closure), any(groovy.lang.Closure), trim()
 at tunehub.LyricsService$_getLyrics_closure1.doCall(LyricsService.groovy:61)
 at tunehub.LyricsService$_getLyrics_closure1.doCall(LyricsService.groovy)
(...truncated...)

Comment: I don't see anything incorrect, maybe I'm just missing it. Are you sure this is where the error is happening?

Comment: Yeah - if I comment out the code block and use HQL instead it works fine. Stranger still, it works in the Grails Console. Only non-standard feature I'm using is a PostgreSQL driver...

Comment: That is bizarre. I'm afraid I don't have any good suggestions.

Comment: seems like an error caused by the dynamic nature of groovy -- you have a String at runtime but are expecting another type.

Answer (score 0):

I often encounter similar problems with Grails. The code is completely as it should be, yet vital GORM methods are mysteriously absent. At the moment, I have a hobby project where DomainClass.list() doesn't work. findAll() should also work, but it doesn't work either. It's a complete mystery. .methods() does include a lot of other methods that Groovy or Grails are supposed to add, but most GORM-specific stuff seems to be missing. Although in the BootStrap, I can create objects of that type and save them to the database.

I don't seem to be having this problem when I create a Grails project at work on my Mac, but it does happen at home on Windows. Weird huh? Is it possible Grails 1.3.6 on Windows is buggy or broken?

Answer (score -1):

what exactly does this constraint mean? Seems suspect to me...

```
static constraints = {
    name()
}
```

is what you want?

```
static constraints = {
    name(nullable:false, blank: false)
}
```

Comment: Every property has a default constraint. When you specify one in the constraints block with no parameters, it takes on the the defaults but scaffolding uses it for order of fields in the view.  It has nothing to do with the OPs problem.